# Have any software distributions been removed from macOS Monterey?

Tags: macos, monterey

Are any software distributions (e.g., python, ruby, perl, etc.) that were included in older versions of macOS not included with macOS Monterey?

Answer (score 5):

[PHP has been removed in Monterey](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/681907). Other software appears to not have changed since Big Sur (11.3).

Comment: Thanks for the info. Any source that shows that other software is still there? Or just nothing else missing as far as you’ve seen?

Comment: Python2 was removed as of macOS 12.3.